# Can i set default alexa slot values?

Tags: python, flask, alexa-skills-kit, slot, home-automation

I've created a home automation system that controls my 3 heating zones, hot water, some lights, green house watering etc.  It's a python back end, apache/web front end etc.

I've been doing some alexa integration, it's going great and all working, but a little inefficient.  I've used Flask-ask on the back end raspberry pi.

At the moment each device/zone has a zone number and it can be boosted for a specific number of minutes at a specific temperature (if it's a heating zone)

The dialogue is along the lines of:  (my invocation name is "control")  check out www.totalcontrol9000.co.uk if you're interested....i've only got one in my house and a friends got one.

- Me: "Alexa, ask control"

  Alexa: "Welcome, you can boost a zone, cancel a boost or request the current temperature."

  me: "please boost zone 3 for 30 minutes at 21 degrees."

  Alexa: "You've requested to boost the main living area zone for 30
  minutes at 21 degrees, is that correct?"

  me : "Yes"
  Alexa : "your boost is activated, good bye."

So this all works fine...but it's quite wordy and i need to remember the zone numbers.  I could trim down the words, but i actually wanted to set up some standard/preset boost commands.

For instance, when i get in from work and its cold in the house, I always just boost for an hour on zone 1 at 20 degrees....

My question is, how can i set up a new intent that passes default slot values....such as:

Me:  "Alexa - ask control."
Alexa: "Welcome......"
Me : "**It's cold**"  (this is the new intent that calls the same function in my code as the full boost command above)
Alexa : "You've requested to boost the main living area zone for 60 mintutes at 20 degrees, is that correct?"

I can find no way to set default slot values in an utterance.  (intent = "Cold", zone slot =1, temp slot = 20, duration slot = 60)

I could code up a new function on the back end, but i would prefer to be able to create new features that feed into an existing function in the code directly from the alexa end, then i'd have far more flexibility.  i could just say "water green house", "i need hot water", "it too dark in the garden" etc to boost various zones for various periods.

many thanks for any info.

G

Comment: for future reference, i also posted this one the AWS forum....they tell me that, as of today, setting slot defaults within an utterance is not currently possible, so i'll create a new intent and some code on the backend to set the defaults.  cheers